# How can I add multiple nodes of same object model to an API POST request using C#

Tags: c#, specflow

I need to construct a POST request to a microservice using C#,then I need to write tests for the response obtained from the service using specflow and nunit.

Sample POST request body is per below . This is for multiple customers

```
  {
  "documentType": "Consent",
  "customers": [
    {
      "fullName": "Jane Smith",
      "custNumber": "7748"
    },
        {
      "fullName": "John Smith",
      "custNumber": "4488"
    },
    {
      "fullName": "Jonny Smith",
      "custNumber": "2748"
    }
  ],
 }
```

My specflow scenario look something like below

```
Scenario Outline: Validate customer names in consent for joint account holders 
Given consent service
And account holder(s) <customername>
When service is called
Then consent has correct customer name 
Examples: 
| customername                        | 
| "Jane Smith,John Smith,Jonny Smith" |
```

Can anyone please help me modify the code for the sepcflow step so that it can cater to multiple customer scenario ?

```
 [Given(@"account holders ""(.*)""")]
 public void GivenAccountHolders(string customername)
    {
        var scen = ScenarioContext.Current.ScenarioInfo.Title;
        if (scen.Contains("individual"))
        {
            api_reqBody["customers"][0] = new JObject
            {
                {"fullName", customername},
                {"custNumber", "7748"},
            };
        }
        else
        {
            string[] split = customername.Split(',');
            api_reqBody["customers"][0] = new JObject
            {
                {"fullName", split[0]},
                {"custNumber", "7748"},
            };
            // How should I add the next two customer details 
        }
    }
```

api_reqBody is declared in the  "Given consent service" step

```
api_reqBody= consentSupport.CreateDefaultConsentBody()
```

The consentSupportclass defines the CreateDefaultConsentBody method as

```
     public static JObject CreateDefaultConsentBody()
        {
            DocumentCreateServiceBody ConsentCreateReqBody = new DocumentCreateServiceBody();
            ConsentCreateReqBody.customers[0] = new customerModel { fullName = "testname", custNumber = "1111" };
}
```

The class for DocumentCreateServiceBody has

```
   public class DocumentCreateServiceBody
    {
        public customerModel[] customers = new customerModel[1];
    }
```

And the class for customer model is

```
  public class customerModel
    {
        public string fullName { get; set; }
        public string custNumber{ get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Where is `api_reqBody` declared?

Comment: api_reqBody is declared at the step binding for [Given(@consent service")] method.

Comment: What type of Object is it? It doesn't really make sense that `api_reqBody` would be of type `customerModel`.

Comment: Hello  Evan Trimboli- I have modified my question content to explain api_reqBody little better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have changed my approach , initiated the customer model dynamically in the step definition of the Given consent service for  and that fixed the problem

Comment: if this solved your problem than mark it as an answer